# rdrobust: plotting graphs for local polynomial estimation

Tags: r, plot, rdd

I am using the standard rdrobust package by Calonico and coauthors, to produce RD estimates and plots in R. It is not clear to me, though, whether there is an automated way to produce graphs with the parameters that emerge from the local polynomial estimation.

Following their example in the rdrobust documentation:

```
library(rdrobust)
data(rdrobust_RDsenate)
vote <- rdrobust_RDsenate$vote
margin <- rdrobust_RDsenate$margin
```

Global plot

```
rdplot(y = vote, x = margin, title = "RD Plot - Senate Elections Data",
   x.label = "Vote Share in Election at time t",
   y.label = "Vote Share in Election at time t+1")
```

Local estimation

```
summary(rdrobust(y = vote, x = margin, all = TRUE))
```

How do I produce a graph using the parameters that are provided by the estimation (i.e. p,h,...)?

Answer (score 0):

I figured, a cumbersome solution can be:

```
rdplot(y = vote, x = margin, 
   binselect = "es", 
   scale = 5,
   kernel = tolower(rdrobust(y = vote, x = margin)$kernel),
   p=rdrobust(y = vote, x = margin)$p,
   h=rdrobust(y = vote, x = margin)$bws[1],
   x.lim = c(rdrobust(y = vote, x = margin)$bws[1],rdrobust(y = vote, x = margin, all = TRUE)$bws[1]),
   title = "RD Plot - Senate Elections Data",
   x.label = "Vote Share in Election at time t",
   y.label = "Vote Share in Election at time t+1",
   ci=95)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way would be to first run rdrobust and store the results:

```
rd1 = rdrobust(y = vote, x = margin)

rdplot1=   rdplot(y = vote, x = margin, 
                  binselect = "es", 
                  scale = 5,
                  kernel = tolower(rd1$kernel),
                  p=rd1$p,
                  h=rd1$bws[1],
                  x.lim = c(-rd1$bws[1],rd1$bws[1]),
                  title = "RD Plot - Senate Elections Data",
                  x.label = "Vote Share in Election at time t",
                  y.label = "Vote Share in Election at time t+1",
                  ci=95)
```